# How can i make a react component button reset all other components to their default value

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import Toolbar from "./Toolbar";


function Lounger(props){
   let [state, changeState] = useState("Available");
   let [color, changeColor] = useState("button-green");

    function colorShift(){
        // color === "button-green" ? 
        // (changeState("Reserved"), changeColor("button-red")) :
        // (changeState("Available"), changeColor("button-green"))

        if(color === "button-green"){
            changeState("Reserved");
            changeColor("button-red");
        }
        else if (color === "button-red"){
            changeState("Available");
            changeColor("button-green");
        }
    }

    

    return(
    <div className="container" >
        <div className={color}>
            <button type="button" className="button"  onClick={colorShift}><p>{state}</p></button>
            {color === "button-red" ? <input className="input" placeholder="Enter room number"/> : null}
        </div>  
    </div>
    );
}

export default Lounger;
```

The Lounger component creates a button when it is clicked it either turns red and says reserved or turns green and says  available according to its previous state. I am trying to make a other component which essentially is a toolbar and one of its buttons resets all the Lounger Components to their default state which is available how could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in a prop to the Lounger component. Then have a `useEffect` listen to it, and then invoke a change of the buttons to its default state.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        changeState("Available");
        changeColor("button-green");
    }, [prop.toolBarVale])

    return(
    <div className="container" >
        <div className={color}>
```

You could re-render the Lounger component when something else changes:

```
<Button onClick={setToolBarValue(x => x++)}>ToolBar Button</Button>

<React.Fragment key={toolBarValue}>
    <Lounger/>
</React.Fragment>
```